# How can i use php's preg_replace with a simple string and wildcards?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

If i have the string `[link="*"]` where * is a wildcard how could i then use php to replace the string with `<a href="*">` where * is the same value as before?

Is preg_replace the best way to do this?

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
preg_replace('~\[link="(.*?)"\]~', '<a href="$1">', $text);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$link = '[link="http://www.google.com/"]';
$link = preg_replace('/\[link="(.*)"\]/', '<a href="$1">', $link);
```