# PHP - Replace specific word inside tag span

Tags: php, replace, tags, preg-replace, cpu-word

I would like to replace the word "**custom**" with

```
<span class="persProd">custom</span>.
```

This is my code but not work:

```
$output = '<a href="www.mysite.com/custom-products"><span>Special custom products</span></a>';
$test = '~<span>custom</span>~';
$outputEdit = preg_replace($test, '<span class="persProd">custom</span>', $output);
echo $outputEdit;
```

How can i do?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i use php's preg\_replace with a simple string and wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050152/how-can-i-use-phps-preg-replace-with-a-simple-string-and-wildcards)

Comment: Also [don't parse html with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this.  Watch out for 'custom' being in the $subject string twice.  It will be replaced both times. I used spaces like so: ' custom '

```
$subject = '<a href="www.mysite.com/custom-products"><span>Special custom products</span></a>';
$search = ' custom ';
$replace = '<span class="persProd"> custom </span>';
$outputEdit = str_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
echo $outputEdit;

Output: <span>Special<span class="persProd"> custom </span>products</span>
```

Here is the [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace) page in the php manual for more.

Answer (score 0):

This is my example and it will working not only with tags (some unique strings too).

```
<?php

function string_between_two_tags($str, $starting_tag, $ending_tag, $string4replace) 
{ 
    $start = strpos($str, $starting_tag)+strlen($starting_tag);
    $end = strpos($str, $ending_tag);
    return substr($str, 0, $start).$string4replace.substr($str, $end);
}



$output = '<a href="www.mysite.com/custom-products"><span>Special custom products</span></a>';
$res = string_between_two_tags($output, '<span>', '</span>', 'custom');
echo $res;

?>
```